# New Lightning Report Builder (beta) - No way to filter nulls from Number fields?

Tags: lightning, report-builder

Just trying out the new LEX report builder UI for the first time, and pretty quickly ran into what appears to be a major limitation: You can't filter on blank/null values for number fields!

[image]

- Add a value to the filter box and the 'Apply' button lights up.
- Alternatively, choose a non-number field to filter on and you can leave the filter box blank and the 'Apply' button lights up.

I assume I'll have to log this as a case with SF, unless I'm missing something obvious... I really hope this doesn't turn into one of those Ideas-that-take-a-decade-to-deliver situations...

Answer (score 1):

Setting the field to "not equal to" and the value to '' worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Not working for me using double single quote (') or single double quote (")